# firebase image size increase

Tags: swift, image, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

please someone explain why this happen?  I was checking so I upload an image directly from firebase and I got its original size, but when I upload it using this code the size increase.

```
 func storeImageInFirebase(){
           let storeageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

           let imageName = UUID().uuidString
           let imagesReference = storeageRef.child("images").child(imageName + ".jpeg")
           let imageData = self.imgView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
           let metaData = StorageMetadata()


         metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
         imagesReference.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData){ (metadate, error)
               in
               guard metadate != nil else{
                   print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                   return
               }
              // Fetch the download URL
               imagesReference.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error)
                   in
                   if error != nil {
                       print("Faild to download url:", error!)
                       return
                   }else{
                       print("original image url ..... \(url?.absoluteString)")
                       // show the url in real database
                    var theUsedURL = self.imgURL = (url?.absoluteString)!

                       self.sendDataToFirebase()

                   }
               })

           }

       }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xretQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is a lossy file format: it stores the image data in a way that compresses it down, depending on the compression factor used.

Image data in an Image View is always uncompressed: it shows the raw bytes of the image.

Most likely, you are:

1. reading the compressed data from the JPEG file, then
2. showing the uncompressed version of that data in the image view, and finally
3. writing the data back to storage as an uncompressed (or less compressed) JPEG file.

If you want to control how big the compressed image is, you can modify the `compressionQuality` in:

```
jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
```

If you want the exact same file to be written, you should not recompress the data, but read the uncompressed data and write that exact data directly back to storage.

Comment: Okay, I tried to use ```let imageData = self.imgView.image?.pngData()``` but I am getting the same issue.

Comment: That still reads the image data back from the image view, so in step 3 from the above. If you want to write the original raw data back, you shouldn't put it in an image view to begin with.

Comment: I wrote a global variable ```var imageSelected2 : UIImage = UIImage.init()``` then in imagePickerController I did ```imageSelected2 = imageSelected``` so I change metaData to ```let imageData = self.imageSelected2.pngData()``` I just noticed no image uploaded to firebase

Comment: Sorry, I did my best to explain the process, because the code is unclear to me. The name `UIImage` suggests that it still puts that data into the UI, which would imply that it's still step 2.

Comment: It's okay. I just was trying to send image to firebase without compression and store it as URL so I can save it in database. Please, could you share document or video link that explain the correct process of sending image to firebase? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: That's described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files
But Firebase doesn't do anything through the Storage API that increases the files size, which seemed to be what you were asking about, and which is likely caused by the compression you specify vs the compression of the original file.